# Stitching 2 videos into one (like panoramic photos)

Tags: video-recording

[image: Soccer field cropped]

I would like to record the indoor soccer games without having to do post-editing if possible.
One camera cannot capture the entire field and goals on each side are cropped as you can see above.

If I use two cameras (each one recording half of the field), would it be possible to stitch those videos into one that covers the entire field?

Also, any other ideas that would allow recording the entire field with one camera and without a cameraperson would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Did a GoPro solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to NOT do any post editing.
And be able to see the whole field with one camera.

I would suggest the gopro.
A bit of a fishbowl effect, but it can work

You can see how it would look like, here is a school baseball game:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is what's called compositing. You can do what you want in any NLE; Premiere, Final Cut X, Lightworks, Media Composer, Vegas, just to name a few. You could also do it in a compositing tool like After Effects or Nuke, but I would stick with a standard NLE for so simple a task.

If you want to do the task live, you could look into a capture card like the Blackmagic Intensity and software like Open Broadcaster Software. Those will allow you to connect your camera to a computer through HDMI and do the compositing live.

Comment: You can make a project that has double width, then composite the images next to each other. The process should be the same, just with minimal overlap. You could also use something like After Effects and actually pan around within the larger stitched video.

Comment: Capturing the video on dropcam, it records directly into the cloud. Talked to an OBS person, he said it would be difficult to feed the videos to OBS(need a plugin) and the quality may not be great. Would Blackmagic allow live compositing from two ip cameras? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The Blackmagic Intensity will allow you to take an HDMI feed into your computer. This will work as long as your cameras have an HDMI out feed, most do.

Comment: @Alper Sorry KC, but this task isn't simple, because of the lens distortion. You can't correct it in Premiere or Final Cut, afaik there are no plugins to do that. I'm just looking for a good 3 camera solution too - see this question: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14600/how-to-stitch-images-from-diy-panorama-video-rig-with-3-canon-60ds maybe the answers help you.

Comment: @poor You won't get significant lens distortion. Based on the pictures, you can see that one camera alone almost does the job. It won't be noticeable if you don't correct for the distortion.

Comment: To stitch it correctly, you have to remove it whether it is significant or not. Besides: In this case it will be significant, because of a maximum focal length of 24.

Comment: @poor To stitch it correctly you need to remove it, but I don't think it will be noticeable if you ignore it. Few people are going to notice a little misalignment at the top of the screen, where there's no action.

Comment: Using Microsoft ICE is a far, far better option.  As @poor mentioned, lens distortion and perspective issues result in some significant oddities beyond simply not lining up and it is noticeable to most people when things that should be square are not.  Microsoft ICE is free and will correct for all of that.

Comment: @AJHenderson I wasn't aware of that program, thanks.